# How do I pack unsigned integers in js?

Tags: javascript

tl;dr - I need a working js equivalent to `struct.pack("!I", <num_here>)`

I'm trying to create an electron frontend for a python chat server I built a while back. When I built said server, I set it up so that all of the data was in json, and when it was sent it was prefixed with the length of the message, packed via `struct.pack`, so that I could determine when I got all of the data. So if I had `'{"USERNAME" : "codeWonderland"}'` I would prefix it with `\x00\x00\x00\x1e`

I found the library [bufferpack](https://github.com/ryanrolds/bufferpack), but it keeps returning `\x00\x00\x00\x00` every time I use the pack operation. There are also a ton of forks of this library, but all of the changes are arbitrary. Furthermore, I wold try and fix the library myself, but literally every variable is just a single letter, so it is very difficult to parse.

Is there any way to accomplish this packing in an easier way? I don't really need to worry about unpacking, because I can quite literally just use the json on the js side when I recieve it from the server, trimming off the length from the string and parsing it normally.

Comment: Take a look at Javascript's [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```js
const output = document.getElementById('output');

function bigEndianOf(n)
{
    return Uint8Array.from([
        (n & 0xFF000000) >>> 24,
        (n & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16,
        (n & 0x0000FF00) >>>  8,
        (n & 0x000000FF) >>>  0,
    ]);
}

document.getElementById('text').addEventListener('change', e => {
  const prefix = new TextDecoder('utf-8').decode(bigEndianOf(e.target.value.length));
  output.value = prefix;
})
```

```html
text: <input id="text" /><br />
length prefix string: <input id="output" readonly />
```